# Assigning Values to Class Variables From an Input String

Tags: java

How to take input string line from a user and assign it to the class variables?
This is my class:

```
public class MyClass {
  String name;
  int age;
  int ph_no;
}
```

Suppose the user inputs something like **Adrian 23 98765432**, my program should assign Adrian to name, and so on. Is there any way to do this?
Please note that the user may also provide something like this:
**23 Adrianne 98765432** and I have to make sure the String provided is mapped to the respective variables.

Comment: For example, [java.util.Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Comment: You're really too far away from an answer for us to describe it to you.  You really may need to sit with your teacher - we can only help with very specific questions.  Right now, you need to flesh out youe class with accessor and mutator methods, and a main method somewhere with a Scanner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try out with this, but its just for sample. There could be many tweaks to break the code. So you have to put in some more stuffs to make it unbreakable.

```
BufferedReader text = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        System.in));
String text2 = text.readLine();
String[] arr = text2.split(" ");
for (String string : arr) {
    try {
        if (string.length() < 3) {
            age = Integer.parseInt(string);
        } else
            ph_no = Integer.parseInt(string); // supposing phno is below integer range
    } catch (Exception e) {
        name = string;
    }
}
System.out.println("NAME ->" + name);
System.out.println("AGE ->" + age);
System.out.println("PHNO ->" + ph_no);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this... where `split` is the input String:

```
public class MyClass 
{

String name;
int age;
int ph_no;

public static void main(String[] args)
{

//Get string input equal to the variable "str"
String[] pieces = str.split("\\s+");
Boolean[] isNumber = new Boolean[pieces.length];

for(int i=0; i<isNumber.length; i++)
{
 boolean[i] = isInteger(pieces[i]);
 }

for(int i=0; i<pieces.length; i++)
{
 if(boolean[i] && pieces[i] > 200)
   ph_no = pieces[i];
 else if(boolean[i] && pieces[i] < 200)
   age = pieces[i];
 else
   name = pieces[i];
}
}

public static boolean isInteger(String s) {
try { 
    Integer.parseInt(s); 
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) { 
    return false; 
 }
 return true;
}
```

This code works under the assumption that your age is less than 200 and the  phone number is greater than 200 or more likely more than 3 digits.